# Search backend for Django App on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-haystack, whoosh

On my development app I'm using a combo of Haystack for search with Whoosh as the backend.

However, when I deploy to Heroku my search is no longer working, even after running `python manage.py update_index`.

Upon some research, I discovered that it's because of Heroku's read-only file system.

Is there any free solution to get around this on Heroku so that I can get search working? The addons I have looked at are ~$20/month and I'd prefer to get started with a free solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really practical to do this without a separate search server.  Storage on Heroku's dynos are not read-only but they are ephemeral and individual to a dyno, and any production application will have at least two dynos.  You might be able to set something up to run on a dyno but it's certain to be complex and fragile, whereas a third party service is turnkey.  Most third party search add-ons scale with usage and many are free at the cheapest level, and if none of them fit the bill then you can always use non-Heroku search services, of which there are many.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Is there a particular one that is free that you would recommend?

Comment: Not yet, but I will have to do this dance for my own project in a few months and will test a variety of services at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the dyno filesystem is [writeable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security). Can you post the error you are getting?

You might want to take another look at Heroku add-ons. There are several Elastic Search add-ons that are in free beta or have free plans. [Haystack supports Elastic Search](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html):

- https://addons.heroku.com/searchbox
- https://addons.heroku.com/bonsai
- https://addons.heroku.com/indexden
- https://addons.heroku.com/foundelasticsearch

Comment: I'm not getting any error-- rather the problem is that it's just not indexing my search at all. I run `python manage.py update_index` yet when I search for an object, it does not show up. On my local machine this issue doesn't occur.